# Set IE8 page title with JavaScript to include French HTML entity

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, internet-explorer-8

Using JavaScript, how can I set the page title (so it works in IE8) to include ᴹᴰ which is the French version of ®?  Charset is utf-8 and cannot be changed.

`document.title = "Bonjour<sup>MD</sup>";  //does not work anywhere`

`document.title = "Bonjourᴹᴰ";  //does not work in WinXP IE8, shows two square characters... even when view source`

Comment: IE8 sucks, probably it's not possible. But consider `®` or `™`, I think they are universal enough.

Comment: @Oriol He wants it in French. MD means Marque Deposé (or Trade Mark in fr) and in some places (like in Quebec, CA) it's an obligation to write these marks in French and not English, even if they are "universal enough".

Comment: In fact, the right character would be [U+1F16B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f16b/index.htm): ``. But it has even less browser support.

Comment: `U+1F16B` would be `document.title = "Bonjour\uD83C\uDD6B";`